# Making Sprite from image from web/server in AndEngine

Tags: android, andengine

I want to make a Sprite from an image which is placed on my server I have complete path of the image. Is it possible to do it in AndEngine.? Currently I am working in GLES 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need generate a link to your image and after,watch this code for load the image in a TextureRegion using HttpURLConnection and InputStream:

```
try {
            ITexture mTexture = new BitmapTexture(pEngine.getTextureManager(), new IInputStreamOpener() {
                @Override
                public InputStream open() throws IOException {

                      URL url = new URL("https://yourImage.png");

                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(input);    
                return in;
                }
            });
mTexture.load();
                TextureRegion MyImageFromWeb = TextureRegionFactory.extractFromTexture(mTexture);



            } catch (IOException e) {
                Debug.e(e);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible you just have to download it first with HttpGet or UrlConnection in Background Thread

But i would recommend you to download all your assets in some kind of splash screen and saving them into sdcard